# Prestashop child theme or Parent theme

Tags: themes, prestashop, parent-child, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on a prestashop site, my mockup has a few things, such as an irregular shaped menu, that I feel might be a difficult to recreate in a child theme.

[Example of the mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2xmX.png)

Particularly I'd like to know seeing my mockup example, which would be the best route, but I guess my question could be generalised in the following manner: "In prestashop, when is a child theme enough, and when are the changes too drastic and require a specific Parent theme to be developed?"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, **it depend on your needs and your objectives**.

**If you are developing a theme** (for example to later sell it) you must create the parent theme.

**If you just want to customize a theme**: changing the menu aspect, change some the JS... a child theme may be enough.

Themes are split in several files so you have to make balance of how many of them will you will need to modify and if you want your theme to be updated.

As you may know, the best feature for child themes is that you only need to create the files you want to override from the parent. Also, you can update the parent and your theme may get updated too (except of the customizations, of course).